# Convert Python Pretty table to CSV using shell or batch command line

Tags: python, csv, prettytable

Whats an easy way convert the output of Python Pretty table to grammatically usable format such as CSV.

The output looks like this :

C:\test> nova list

```
    spu+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
     | ID                                   | Name   | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks                          |
     +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
     | 6bca09f8-a320-44d4-a11f-647dcec0aaa1 | tester | ACTIVE | -          |  Running     | OpenStack-net=10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.3 |
     +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is not generated by a script, it gets generated by OpenStack CLI  http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/content/ output, they use pretty tables

Comment: I can comment now!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will get you close:

```
nova list | grep -v '\-\-\-\-' | sed 's/^[^|]\+|//g' | sed 's/|\(.\)/,\1/g' | tr '|' '\n'
```

This will strip the --- lines
Remove the leading |
Replace all but the last | with ,
Replace the last | with \n

Comment: Thanks for looking into it but i think there should be an escape somewhere ?
C:\test> nova list | grep -V '----' | sed 's/^[^|]\+|//g' | sed 's/|\(.\)/,\1/g' | tr '|' '\n'
grep: unrecognized option '----'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.

Comment: its not complaining about the v , it does not like the dashes:

grep: unrecognized option '----'

Answer (score 3):

Here's a real ugly one-liner

```
import csv

s = """\
  spu+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
     | ID                                   | Name   | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks                          |
     +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
     | 6bca09f8-a320-44d4-a11f-647dcec0aaa1 | tester | ACTIVE | -          |  Running     | OpenStack-net=10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.3 |
     +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+"""

result = [tuple(filter(None, map(str.strip, splitline))) for line in s.splitlines() for splitline in [line.split("|")] if len(splitline) > 1]

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
    writer.writerows(result)
```

I can unwrap it a bit to make it nicer:

```
splitlines = s.splitlines()
splitdata = line.split("|")
splitdata = filter(lambda line: len(line) > 1, data)
# toss the lines that don't have any data in them -- pure separator lines
header, *data = [[field.strip() for field in line if field.strip()] for line in splitdata]

result = [header] + data
# I'm really just separating these, then re-joining them, but sometimes having
# the headers separately is an important thing!
```

Or possibly more helpful:

```
result = []

for line in s.splitlines():
    splitdata = line.split("|")
    if len(splitdata) == 1:
        continue  # skip lines with no separators
    linedata = []
    for field in splitdata:
        field = field.strip()
        if field:
            linedata.append(field)
    result.append(linedata)
```

Answer (score 2):

@AdamSmith's answer has a nice method for parsing the raw table string. Here are a few additions to turn it into a generic function (I chose not to use the `csv` module so there are no additional dependencies)

```
def ptable_to_csv(table, filename, headers=True):
    """Save PrettyTable results to a CSV file.

    Adapted from @AdamSmith https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128226

    :param PrettyTable table: Table object to get data from.
    :param str filename: Filepath for the output CSV.
    :param bool headers: Whether to include the header row in the CSV.
    :return: None
    """
    raw = table.get_string()
    data = [tuple(filter(None, map(str.strip, splitline)))
            for line in raw.splitlines()
            for splitline in [line.split('|')] if len(splitline) > 1]
    if table.title is not None:
        data = data[1:]
    if not headers:
        data = data[1:]
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for d in data:
            f.write('{}\n'.format(','.join(d)))
```

Comment: @DhairyTripathi Could it be because `len(data) == 0`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a regular expression. It also works for an arbitrary number of columns (the number of columns is determined by counting the number of plus signs in the first input line).

```
input_string = """spu+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
     | ID                                   | Name   | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks                          |
     +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
     | 6bca09f8-a320-44d4-a11f-647dcec0aaa1 | tester | ACTIVE | -          |  Running     | OpenStack-net=10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.3 |
     +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+"""

import re, csv, sys
def pretty_table_to_tuples(input_str):
    lines = input_str.split("\n")
    num_columns = len(re.findall("\+", lines[0])) - 1
    line_regex = r"\|" + (r" +(.*?) +\|"*num_columns)
    for line in lines:
        m = re.match(line_regex, line.strip())
        if m:
            yield m.groups()

w = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
w.writerows(pretty_table_to_tuples(input_string))
```